# FlyWay schemas for different db type

Tags: spring-boot, flyway

is it possible in Flyway to define multiple schemas for different DB type? For exp I have Oracle, Postgres in Mssql db. I would like to know how folder should structure in this case should be defined and how files should be organised. What about flyway config in this case?

thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure simply put them in the accoring folders. The path is `db/migration/{vendor}`

So for example:

```
db/migration/mssql
db/migration/oracle
```

Please read the documentation: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#howto.data-initialization.migration-tool